# setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds is not working properly

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've an email field as `EditText`. I'm trying to add a green-tick icon at the end of the text field when the validation is true, and `setError` when it is false.

Here's the piece of code I'm using right now:

```
email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                String mail = email.getText().toString();
                if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()) {
                    email.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
                } 
                else {
                    Log.i("YaY","Email is valid!!!");
                    email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.validated, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**PROBLEM:**

Though I can see the log `Yay: Email is valid!!!`, it seems no icon is set as I can't see it.
But when I change the `if-condition` to `false`, which means `setError` will never be called, I can see the log as well as the icon.

Any explanations upon why I'm seeing this strange behavior? What am I missing?

Answer (score 12):

try removing the icon from xml if you are setting any 
and set both images from the code
for some reason the image does not refresh if you set one from xml

and use

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
          numTxt.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {    
          numTxt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not setting any icons from xml. Please explain your answer properly.

Comment: @Akeshwar,   Just convert the xml into the Drawable Object , Then just pass that to the suggested arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is a bug but I am able to workaround this by setting the drawable to zero (0) first before assigning the new drawable.

In your case, you can try the following:

```
Log.i("YaY","Email is valid!!!");
email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.validated, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like they have some bug in it. You need to do init set (like you did with zeros) and then real set of the value. Then it'll work. Crazy.