# android - setCompoundDrawables, setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBoundsis not show icon

Tags: android

When I setCompoundDrawables or setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds with a drawable in a EditText. Everytimes show layout of activity, I'm trying to add a x icon at the end of the text field but it's not working in first create. But refresh, icon x showing.
Do setCompoundDrawables set icon failed?
Please Help me.
It is sample problem same but i can't fix my problem: [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944012/setcompounddrawableswithintrinsicbounds-is-not-working-properly)

```
drawXRemove = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_iconX);
drawXRemove.setBounds(0, 0, drawXRemove.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawMarkXRemove.getIntrinsicHeight());
editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawXRemove, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting Compound Drawable in wrong way. use:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,drawXRemove, 0);
```

OR

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,R.drawable.ic_iconX, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using icon directly from drawable as below

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I already has do it and it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I do it. It's problem when different func call set null for EditText.

Comment: Please how did you fix it? I don't understand.